# BottomNavigationView only hiding on scroll for one fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have a `BottomNavigationView` in my `activity_main.xml`, along with a `FrameLayout` to swap between 3 fragments.

I'm using `CoordinatorLayout`.

I'm trying to make it so that when the fragment in the `FrameLayout` is scrolled, the navigation bar hides itself.

I've added the behaviour attribute to the the nav bar in my layout, and it's working for the first fragment, which is a `RelativeLayout` with a `RecyclerView` in it.

However, when I switch the a different fragment, which is a `ScrollView`, the nav bar no longer hides itself.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:background="@color/colorMain"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/mainPaddingTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/mainPaddingTop"
            android:layout_above="@id/mainPaddingBottom"
            android:id="@+id/frag_container"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <View
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/mainPaddingBottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorMain"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorMain">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/accountButton"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:tint="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/account" />

        <ImageButton
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:tint="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_magnify"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/account" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:fontFamily="@font/productsansmedium"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        android:background="@color/bottomNavColor"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navbar_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navbar_color_selector"
        app:elevation="26dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment_start.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StartFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_centre.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".CentreFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/productsansmedium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:text="@string/section_1"
            android:id="@+id/section1Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/horizontalScroll"
            android:fontFamily="@font/productsansmedium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:text="@string/section_2"
            android:id="@+id/section2Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/section2Text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    app:strokeWidth="1.5dp"
                    app:strokeColor="@color/colorQuad"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorMain"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
                    android:layout_width="38dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:tint="@color/colorSecondary"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_pound"
                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="22dp"/>

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/productsansmedium"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/category_1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                        android:tint="@color/colorQuad"
                        android:src="@drawable/line_seperator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    app:strokeWidth="1.5dp"
                    app:strokeColor="@color/colorQuad"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorMain"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
                    android:layout_width="38dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:tint="@color/colorSecondary"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_pound"
                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="22dp"/>

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/productsansmedium"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/category_2" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                        android:tint="@color/colorQuad"
                        android:src="@drawable/line_seperator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    app:strokeWidth="1.5dp"
                    app:strokeColor="@color/colorQuad"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorMain"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
                    android:layout_width="38dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:tint="@color/colorSecondary"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_pound"
                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="22dp"/>

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/productsansmedium"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/category_3" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                        android:tint="@color/colorQuad"
                        android:src="@drawable/line_seperator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    app:strokeWidth="1.5dp"
                    app:strokeColor="@color/colorQuad"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorMain"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
                    android:layout_width="38dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:tint="@color/colorSecondary"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_pound"
                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="22dp"/>

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/productsansmedium"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/category_4" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                        android:tint="@color/colorQuad"
                        android:src="@drawable/line_seperator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    app:strokeWidth="1.5dp"
                    app:strokeColor="@color/colorQuad"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorMain"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
                    android:layout_width="38dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:tint="@color/colorSecondary"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_pound"
                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="22dp"/>

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/productsansmedium"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/category_5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                        android:tint="@color/colorQuad"
                        android:src="@drawable/line_seperator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    app:strokeWidth="1.5dp"
                    app:strokeColor="@color/colorQuad"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorMain"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
                    android:layout_width="38dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:tint="@color/colorSecondary"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_pound"
                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="22dp"/>

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/productsansmedium"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/category_6" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                        android:tint="@color/colorQuad"
                        android:src="@drawable/line_seperator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    app:strokeWidth="1.5dp"
                    app:strokeColor="@color/colorQuad"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorMain"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
                    android:layout_width="38dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:tint="@color/colorSecondary"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_pound"
                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="22dp"/>

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/productsansmedium"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/category_7" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                        android:tint="@color/colorQuad"
                        android:src="@drawable/line_seperator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    app:strokeWidth="1.5dp"
                    app:strokeColor="@color/colorQuad"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorMain"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
                    android:layout_width="38dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:tint="@color/colorSecondary"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_pound"
                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="22dp"/>

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/productsansmedium"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/category_8" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                        android:tint="@color/colorQuad"
                        android:src="@drawable/line_seperator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The result is that when I scroll in the second fragment, the bar doesn't hide itself and covers up the bottom of the fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior">

    <!-- Your scrolling content -->

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Hope it solves.